# How to flip a svg path in html?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, svg, path

I'd like to use an icon from `bootstrap`, but I need it flipped vertically:

https://icons.getbootstrap.com/icons/arrow-left-right/

What I'd rather need is a *arrow-right-left*, so that the upper arrow points to the right.

I tried to transform with `transform="scale(-1 1) translate(-1260 0)"`, but that did not work:

https://jsfiddle.net/j63zpwqr/

So how could I flip a path on the Y-axis?

Comment: ``transform="scale(-1 1)"`` on the SVG should do it.

Comment: That's what I also tried of course. But as soon as I add any transformation, the icon is gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed path info from 3 paths into 1 because Bootstrap icons are bloated,
using https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/
That also changed the SVG from Absolute positioning to Relative

a `transform="scale(-1 1)` flips the image

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="160" height="160" fill="red" 
     class="bi bi-arrow-left-right" 
     viewBox="0 0 16 16" 
     transform="scale(-1 1)">
  <path d="m10.15 7.65a.5.5 0 01.71 0l3 3a.5.5 0 010 .71l-3 3a.5.5 0 01-.71-.71l2.65-2.65l-2.65-2.65a.5.5 0 010-.71zm-8.15 3.35a.5.5 0 01.5-.5h10.5a.5.5 0 010 1h-10.5a.5.5 0 01-.5-.5zm3.85-9.35a.5.5 0 010 .71l-2.65 2.65l2.65 2.65a.5.5 0 11-.71.71l-3-3a.5.5 0 010-.71l3-3a.5.5 0 01.71 0zm-3.35 3.35a.5.5 0 01.5-.5h10.5a.5.5 0 010 1h-10.5a.5.5 0 01-.5-.5z" />
</svg>
```

Comment: With your help I discovered that I added the `transform` statement to `path` instead of `svg`. Adding it to the correct element fixed it.